# idle-vue-3 is NOT really "vue 3"

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex, typeerror, quasar

The github repositories mentioned in https://www.npmjs.com/package/idle-vue-3/v/1.0.1 do not have issues page. So, I guess I have to post it here. The documentation provided is not really Vue 3 at all. Many of the APIs used in the documentation are obsolete. Things like `import Vue from 'vue';`, `Vue.use`, etc. WTF is that project owner doing!?!

I bump into error with the following code snippet:

```
  app.use(IdleVue, {
    eventEmitter: Vue,
    //store,
    store: Store,
    idleTime: idleTimeInMillis,
    startAtIdle: false
  });
```

`Store` is imported from another `.js` file:

```
export default async () => {
  const Store = createStore({
    modules: {
      rules,
      utils
    },

    // enable strict mode (adds overhead!)
    // for dev mode only
    state: {
      clients: []
    },

    mutations: vuexfireMutations,

    actions: {
      bindClient: firestoreAction(async (context, ref) => {
        return await context.bindFirestoreRef("clients", ref);
      })
    },
    strict: process.env.DEV
  });
  return Store;
}
```

The browser console shows the following error:

```
boot error: TypeError: r.registerModule is not a function
```

which happens on line   `app.use(IdleVue, {`. Any advice and insight is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean obsolete? It's scheduled to be deprecated but it's not deprecated yet.

> WTF is that project owner doing!?!

The project owner did what he wanted, create an `idle-js` wrapper for Vue.

Vue 3 was officially release in September 2020.

`idle-vue` existed even back in 2019.

If you checked the repo, you'd see it was a fork.

The forked repo is released under the name `idle-vue`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/idle-vue

`idle-vue-2` is taken but empty: https://www.npmjs.com/package/idle-vue-2

`idle-vue-3` is the fork version with more changes applied to it.

Check the issue: https://github.com/soixantecircuits/idle-vue/issues/49 for your question.

Just use `idle-js` yourself or make a fork of your own and support Vue 3.